# Does the characteristic polynomial $c(f)=0$ divide polynomials of higher degree?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I need some clarification with a proof of mine.

Suppose $f: V \rightarrow V$ is linear with V being a 4-dimensional vector space. The eigenvalues of f are 3,5,8. Prove that $(f-3id_V)^2(f-5id_V)^2(f-8id_V)^2=0$.

$Proof$

Since the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $f$, we know that $c(x)=(x-3)(x-5)(x-8)p(x)$ where $p(x)=(x-r), r\in \{3,5,8\}$. Since for all $r\in \{3,5,8\} (c(f)=0)$ and $c(x)$ divides $q(x)$, we must have q(f)=0.

$QED$

Am I right in making the implication of the last sentence? $c(f)$ divides $q(f)$ since $0\times s(x) = 0$, but my intuition leads me to think zero cannot divide zero, hence my doubt. Is there some theorem of proposition that I should employ or any clarification? Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This may sound stupid but is 0 divides 0 different to 0 divided by 0?